# How can I cache an external java-script file with GenerateSW and workbox

Tags: vue.js, webpack, workbox

I'm using Workbox with Vue and GenerateSW. Caching fonts, my own JS-Files and my css + html works just fine but how can I configure WB to cache an external JS-File???

public folder / index.html

```
....
<head>
<script src="https://code.iconify.design/2/2.0.4/iconify.min.js"></script>
</head>...
```

vue.config.js:

```
const WorkboxPlugin = require('workbox-webpack-plugin')
configureWebpack: {
plugins: [
    ...
    new WorkboxPlugin.GenerateSW({
        runtimeCaching: [
            {
                handler: 'StaleWhileRevalidate',
                method: 'GET',
                urlPattern: /\.(?:js)$/,
                options: {
                    cacheName: 'javascript'
                }
            },
        ]
    })]
}
```

When I use `urlPattern: /^https:\/\/code.iconify.design/,` caching works
but why does it fail with the "extension" pattern: `urlPattern: /\.(?:js)$/,`

Google shows a recipe for this case: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/common-recipes#cache_css_and_javascript_files

but they provide not recipe for their own "GenerateSW"-approach.

Answer (score 0):

Workbox's `RegExp` routes will only match cross-origin requests if the pattern provided matches starting with the first character of the URL. There are more details about this behavior [in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-routing#how_to_register_a_regular_expression_route).

`urlPattern` actually does support the same callback-based approached mentioned elsewhere in the docs, and I think that ends up being clearer than `RegExp`s for most use cases:

```
new WorkboxPlugin.GenerateSW({
  runtimeCaching: [{
    handler: 'StaleWhileRevalidate',
    method: 'GET',
    urlPattern: ({ request }) => request.destination === 'script',
    options: {
      cacheName: 'javascript'
    }
  }]
})]
```